# Find $\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$

Tags: partial-derivative

Given $$x=\frac{u+v}{1-uv}$$ and $$y=\arctan\left(u\right)+\arctan\left(v\right)$$

Then find $$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$$

---

I don't understand the notation $(x,y)$ or $(u,v)$,since I've always seen a function instead of $(x,y)$ and a variable instead of $(u,v)$,can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the notation $(x,y)$ or $(u,v)$,since I've always seen a function instead of $(x,y)$ and a variable instead of $(u,v)$,can someone help?

It could be confusing if you're thinking about the standard notation for a partial derivative of a function of several variables, but it's not *that* different: $x$ and $y$ are in fact functions of $u$ and $v$.

The notation
$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \tag{1}$$
refers to the **Jacobian** (determinant) which is, in this case:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\[4pt] \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
So you should remember $(1)$ as a (compact) *notation* for $(2)$.

I would expect your text(book) to introduce this notation, if you're giving this kind of exercise.

Comment: It's $0$, indeed.

Comment: I think you were still editing when I responded but your result is correct, yes!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, $$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$$ means, that you have to find the determinant of a Jacobian matrix, given $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$, i.e.:

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} =
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}  & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}.$$
Taking partial derivatives of your given $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$.